# UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling, paging with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

In my application, I would like to have a horizontal scrollview with different address cards as shown in the below image.

[image: Address Cards]

I added a scrollview and its content view to its viewcontroller via storyboard. Following are the constraints.

[image: Autolayout Tree]

I also created a .xib file for a address card. I am loading this .xib via loadNibNamed api whenever I need address card as I don't know how many address cards I need.  And it is dynamic. Below is the code I added.

```
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

RVXVoterView *voterView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RVXVoterView" owner:nil options:nil][0];
[self.contentView addSubview:voterView];

voterView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.scrollView, self.contentView, voterView);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[voterView]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[voterView]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

RVXVoterView *voterView1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RVXVoterView" owner:nil options:nil][0];
[self.contentView addSubview:voterView1];

voterView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.scrollView, self.contentView, voterView, voterView1);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[voterView1]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:voterView1
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:voterView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            multiplier:1
                                                              constant:0]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[voterView]-15-[voterView1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
RVXLOG(@"content size is : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
[self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
```

In the above code, I added just 2 cards as an initial setup.
Below is the final screen I got. But my question is, why it is not scrollable. I checked all the primary things which prevent scrolling. What I am missing. Please help me.
[image: Final result]

**Update:** I found that, width of contentView is not increasing even when I added a new card. Initially, width of contentView is equal to screen width. When I add a new card, it should increases by new card width. But this is not happening. It is always showing the same width(375 for iPhone6).

Comment: what are the values of scrollview width and content view width at runtime? if they are same then when you are changing the content size of scroll view just add some more amount to it. like 10 or 20 and it will be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

To make `UIScrollView` scroll with AutoLayout, you have to make sure all subviews tie to all four edges of the scroll view. From your code I can see that you tied the first view(voterView) to all four edges of the contentView, and tried to tie the second view(voterView1) to the right of the first view, I don't think that would work since the right of the first view was already tied to its parent(the contentView).

First add `width` and `height` constraints for the subviews as you already did in the code you demonstrated, then try the following VFL:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(voterView);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[voterView]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[voterView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(voterView, voterView1);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[voterView]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[voterView]-15-[voterView1]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and patients. But unfortunately there is no improvement after adding the changes you mentioned.

Comment: It may be caused by some other issues I am not aware of. I wrote a useful class that makes it easier to work with UIScrollView + AutoLayout, you may want to check out the demo and  see if it suits your needs.  https://github.com/neevek/Easy-UIScrollView-with-AutoLayout